# MySQL String, check is column exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating something where a column is created for the current date if it does not exist. This is the current query to check for a column name and create one if it does not exist. The variable is `$date` And this does not work, please can somebody suggest what is wrong with it.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
    IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Scouts' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$date'
    )
    BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE Scouts ADD '$date' VARCHAR( 255 )
    END
");
```

SQL injection is not a problem as it is only being hosted on a local machine.
Sorry if it wasn't clear at first.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This isn't working and i don't know why, I would like some suggestions.

Comment: Is this code written inside a stored procedure?  MySQL only recognizes `if` in the body of a stored procedure, function, or trigger.

Comment: No, just in a MySQL query in PHP

Comment: do you have more code?  and i noticed you are trying to insert the php variable directly into the string? could be a security risk (sql injection)

Comment: You have your answer.  You could do this in a stored procedure.  Modifying tables on the fly seems like a dangerous application design.

Comment: And lot of fun. Just thinking of a huge table adding/deleting columns ...

Comment: I think you need to re-think your table structure. This just doesn't seem like a great idea. Perhaps you can explain what you're trying to accomplish here. Also, just because something is being hosted on a local machine doesn't mean you don't need to worry about sanitizing data. Better to learn and do it right the first time :)